# Which items has my access been restricted to?

Tags: google-drive

I recently saw this message in my *Recent activity* feed in Google Drive:

```
[Name Redacted] restricted access to 3 items
```

How do i find out which items I've lost access to?

My drive has a large number of documents on it, and i'd like to be able to ask for access back to items that are relevant, soon after the access was changed - and not much later, when the other person might not remember they've changed things.